# Why System.out.println can't print out a string value (in my particular case)?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner, println, system.out

My program should ask users to enter some value and evetually those value should be printed out depending on the menu option choosen (in my case it's *3*). I have used `System.out.println("Your name: " + name);` to print out the name inserted by user, but unfortunately it can't print out the name. The line is just left empty. Why so? How can I fix it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userChoose;
    String name = null;
    int accNum = 0;
    double initiateAmount = 0;
    double newAmm = 0;

    double depOrWith = 0;
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n"
            + "...................\n"
            + "...................\n\n"
            + "Choose your optiin:\n"
            + "1. Create new account\n"
            + "2. Deposit/withdraw\n"
            + "3. View details\n"
            + "4. Deleting an account\n"//not used yet
            + "5. View all the accounts\n"//not used yet
            + "6. Quit\n\n");
    System.out.println("*************\n"
            + "************");
    while (true) {
        userChoose = sc.nextInt();

        if (userChoose == 1) {

            System.out.println("Enter your full name:");

            name = sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

            accNum = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter an initiating amount:");

            initiateAmount = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                    + "------------");
        } else if (userChoose == 2) {

            System.out.println("Enter negative value to withdraw and positive to deposit");
            depOrWith = sc.nextInt();
            if (depOrWith < 0) {

               initiateAmount = initiateAmount + depOrWith;
            } else {

               initiateAmount = initiateAmount + depOrWith;
            }

            System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                    + "------------");

        } else if (userChoose == 3) {

            System.out.println("Your name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Your account number: " + accNum);
            System.out.println("Your current balance: " + initiateAmount);
            System.out.println("\n-----------\n"
                    + "------------");
        } else if (userChoose == 6) {

            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you execute the case 1 first? Because that is where the input is read and stored in `name`

Comment: Please learn to format your code correctly; this is wholly illegible.

Comment: name is null in option 3, also use switch to make the conditions simpler.

Comment: Boris the Spider, its easy to comment like this, but it's not easy to provide a good answer. By the way, can u tell me the wrong with my code formatting? which parth looks illigible and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After selecting the option and pressing Enter, the `Scanner` is not reading the newline. Afterwards when `name = sc.nextLine();` is called it will only read the new line following the selected option and `name` will be assigned the empty string. To solve this, simply add a call `nextLine` after reading the selected option, and remove the duplicate `nextLine` when reading the name:

```
while (true) {
    userChoose = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    if (userChoose == 1) {

        System.out.println("Enter your full name:");

        name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

        ...
```

Comment: manouti, thanks, it makes a lots of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the Blank `nextLine()` and the assigning one.

```
System.out.println("Enter your full name:");

        sc.nextLine();
        name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Choose an account number:");

        accNum = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: Anjula_Ranasinghe, thnak u, it also works i have tasted. Since i already got manouti's answer, i have accepted his. but anyway ur solution is simple and nice.

Comment: Yes, His answer explains better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

name is null.  If the user selects three you haven't actually assigned a value to the name variable yet, that only happens if they choose 1

Answer (score 0):

When you select the option `3` you're not setting the `name` value which defaults to `null`, so it's printing `Your name: null`

You need to read and assign `name` value if you want something to be printed.